# Is it possible to integrate this in Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

I am trying to find the volume bounded by the following surfaces.

$\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$
$\ z = r^2$

I would like to set up an integral for this in Cartesian, Cylindrical, and Spherical coordinate systems. I am stuck on this because I don't quite know what to do with the r in the second surface when it comes to Cartesian coordinates.

Using $\ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $(I thought this could only be used when going from Cartesian to Cylindrical, but I don't know what else to do with it) I got this far for Cartesian.

$\ \int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} 1 dzdxdy $

But I don't think this is right as it yields a negative result.

Comment: What is $r$ in the second.

Comment: r is not given.

Comment: He means, "is r the polar or spherical radial distance"?

Comment: I have no idea. That is all that is given in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice it on disks along z axis, each disk is a cylinder with height equal to $dz$ and base is a circle with radius $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Since $x^2+y^2=4-z^2$ you have $\int_{r^2}^2(4-z^2)\pi dz$